# delete some row in a mysql query

Tags: mysql

Here under a mysql request

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(codeAdherent), dateFin   
FROM hs  
WHERE
codeFamilleArticle IN ('ABO', 'ABOW')  
AND dateFin >= date('2018-01-01')  
ORDER BY codeAdherent ASC

codeAdherent    date  
1099        2018-12-31  
1099        2019-12-31  
1318        2018-12-31  
1392        2018-12-31  
1392        2019-12-31  
1415        2018-12-31  
1415        2019-12-31  
1600        2018-12-31  
1785        2018-12-31  
1785        2019-12-31  
1806        2018-12-31  
1806        2019-12-31  
1825        2018-12-31  
1983        2019-12-31  
2039        2018-12-31  
2039        2019-12-31
```

Sometimes codeAdherent appears twice, one time for 2018-12-31 and another time for 2019-12-31.
I would like to discard rows which appear twice and keep only those which appear one time with year 2018.
It's possible to do this with PHP but is there a way to only use a query ?

Comment: you can use count() and having() to get desire result.

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT(codeAdherent), dateFin` ... `DISTINCT` is a KEYWORD, not a function in MySQL.. You are using it wrong.. I think you are expecting to get unique codeAdherent per dateFin?  You should also provide expected results see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) how to provide

Comment: Clarify what happens if there is a result for 2019 but no corresponding result for 2018

Comment: I did that mistake from a while without known problem. I will correct this.

Comment: If a result appear one time I keep it. If a result appear twice, I delete two rows.

Comment: The subject of this question and the details are somewhat confusing. At first it seemed like you were asking to delete a record from a table. You should not use the word DELETE if you just want to see different results from your query.

Comment: I agree with you, and the question will be more precise if I wrote: I would like to discard rows when codeAdherent appears twice in the result and keep only those which appear one time with year 2018.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT codeAdherent, MIN(dateFin) as dateFin 
FROM hs WHERE codeFamilleArticle IN ('ABO', 'ABOW') 
GROUP BY codeAdherent 
ORDER BY codeAdherent ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

A `GROUP BY` with a `HAVING` clause could return the unique only.

```
SELECT codeAdherent, MAX(dateFin) AS dateFin
FROM hs  
WHERE codeFamilleArticle IN ('ABO','ABOW')
  AND dateFin >= date('2018-01-01')
GROUP BY codeAdherent
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY codeAdherent ASC
```